# Current Boosting Circuit

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

So I am using a LM7805 regulator in a project, hoping to get 1.5A out, but in testing I only got about 0.7A out. I am looking to use a circuit like the one in the picture below, and was wondering if it is feasible if I am supplying about 7.5V in. Also looking to see what value the resistor attached to the base is. If I am getting 0.7A, do I make it so the transistor turns on when the current is 0.7, then the rest is supplied by the pnp? Thanks[image]

Comment: 7.5V in is barely enough for the 7805 to regulate, even before you consider the voltage drop across R1. So, this probably won't work. Look for a 1.5A LDO regulator.

Comment: *If I am getting 0.7A, do I make it so the transistor turns on when the current is 0.7, then the rest is supplied by the pnp?* Use the given formula, what value are you using for R1? At 3 Ohm the PNP will start to conduct when there is 0.7 V / 3 Ohm = 0.23 A flowing. Are you cooling the PNP and the LM7805 sufficiently?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have an overhead voltage of only 2.5V. Although the datasheet spec is for 7V input min (2V overhead), that's at 1A. For higher currents the overhead could be higher.

As for your proposal, note that Q1 won't do anything until its base is 0.7V below the input. That means it won't begin to conduct until the IR drop across R1 is at least 0.7V, making the 7805 input 7.5 - 0.7V = 6.8V. This is not enough overhead for the 7805 to work.

So you have an opportunity: **forget about the 7805**. Consider using a DC-DC module instead. There are types are available in the 3-pin TO-220 footprint and in most cases can drop right in in place of a 7805. And a bonus: much lower overhead voltage, they’ll work on 7.5V.

Here's an introduction to these by TI: https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/posts/upgrade-your-to-220-linear-regulator-with-a-pin-compatible-buck-power-module

MPS has a range of these, including this 5V/2A module in their portfolio: https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mezd71202a-g.html

Murata / OKI: https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/productdetail?partno=OKI-78SR-5%2F1.5-W36-C

CUI: https://www.cui.com/product/dc-dc-converters/non-isolated/v78-1500r-series

You can also consider a more modern LDO if for some reason a switching regulator is a problem for your application.

Comment: I agree and think this is a really good segue into learning about DC-DC converters. I'm glad to see you pressing it. Today, with so many helpful ICs around, it's almost criminal not to get up to speed. This means learning about inductors (and transformers.) So it takes a little more time. And, if a hobbyist and wanting to design more complex arrangements where you cannot just buy an inductor/transformer, then also how to make them, by hand. (A business can hire a company to design and manufacture specialty items like that. A hobbyist cannot afford to do so.) Anyway, +1.